# Value not updated in databases after validation and save success

Tags: php, controller, yii2, return-value

Hi everyone i'm having trouble with my software developed with yii2.
I Have a model called Anagrafica and with its primary key id. With this model everything works.
I also have a model called AnagraficaOpzioniCarriera which extend the first one.

I have a view anagrafica/index that show a Kartik grid with the data of people enrolled that you can find in anagrafica. Admin user can update the data of an Anagrafica model by clicking on an the attribute "cognome" that render to anagrafica/update.

this is the command that call the controller AnagraficaController to reach anagrafica/update

`'cognome'=>Grid::Labels('cognome',['anagrafica/update'],\app\helpers\Permits::allow('anagrafica','update'),'id','btn','info','10%'),`

This is AnagraficaController

```
public function actionUpdate($id,$error=0,$message='')
     {
         $id = (int)$id;
        
         $model = Anagrafica::findOne(['id' => $id]);
         $model->scenario = 'update';
        
         if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            
             if($model->validate()){
             }
                
             if($model->save(false)){
                 return $this->redirect(['anagrafica/update','id'=>$model->id]);
             }
         } 
     }
     return $this->render('update', ['model' => $model, 'extended'=>true]);
}
```

i removed some portions of code to semplify it, but this is the core.

One time the view anagrafica/update is reached in this page i have an ActiveForm to modify data of the model and i have a render to a grid that show the attributes contained in AnagraficaOpzioniCarriera about the $model that i'm updating.

`<?= $this->render('_opzioni_carriera',['parent'=>$model]); ?>`

anagrafica/_opzioni_carriera view contain a Kartik grid that shows the column in the model AnagraficaOpzioniCarriera

```
<?php

use kartik\grid\GridView;
use kartik\select2\Select2;
use kartik\widgets\ActiveForm;
use kartik\editable\Editable;
use kartik\widgets\SwitchInput;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use app\helpers\Autoconfigurazione;
use app\models\AnagraficaOpzioniCarriera;
use app\helpers\Grid;
use yii\helpers\Html;
use app\helpers\UserInfo;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model app\models\AnagraficaOpzioniCarriera*/
$model = new AnagraficaOpzioniCarriera(['scenario'=>'search']);
?>

<div class="">
<?php 
    echo GridView::widget([
        'options'=>[
        'id'=>'opzioni_carriera',
    ],
    'dataProvider'=> $model->search($parent->id,Yii::$app->request->queryParams),
    'showPageSummary'=>false,
    'headerRowOptions'=>['class'=>'kartik-sheet-style'],        
    'pjax'=>true, // pjax is set to always true for this demo
    'pjaxSettings'=>[
        'neverTimeout'=>true,
    ],
    'toolbar'=> [
        [
                'content'=>''
        ],
        ],
        'panel'=>[
        'heading'=>false,
        'footer'=>false,
        'after'=>false,
    ],
    'columns' => Grid::gridColumns([
        'model'=>$model,
        'checkbox'=>false,
        'remove'=>Grid::gridRemove($model),
        'extraOptions' =>[
            'cashback' =>Grid::YNColumn('cashback',['anagrafica-opzioni-carriera/update', 'id' => $parent->id],'left',true,'5%'),
            'compensa'=>Grid::YNColumn('compensa',['anagrafica-opzioni-carriera/update', 'id' => $parent->id],'left',true,'5%'),                    
            'associazione'=>Grid::YNColumn('associazione',['anagrafica-opzioni-carriera/update', 'id' => $parent->id],'left',true,'5%'),                   
            'formazione'=>Grid::YNColumn('formazione',['anagrafica-opzioni-carriera/update', 'id' => $parent->id],'left',true,'5%'),
        ],
    ]);


?>


</div>
```

cashback, compensa etc.. are the attributes in the model AnagraficaOpzioniCarriera.
Here when i try to update this attributes everything looks fine, the function model->validate() and model->load returns true value, but at the end of the process doesn't works.
Honestly i don't know what i have to return from the function of the controller.

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
 {                 
                
    $model = AnagraficaOpzioniCarriera::findOne(['id_anagrafica' => $id]);
    if (!$model) {
            // Se l'anagrafica opzioni carriera non esiste, genera un'eccezione 404
            throw new \yii\web\NotFoundHttpException(Yii::t('app', 'The requested page does not             exist.'));
        }
        
        $model->scenario = 'update';
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {
            if(Yii::$app->request->post('cashback') != null) $model->cashback = Yii::$app->request->post('cashback');
            if(Yii::$app->request->post('compensa') != null) $model->cashback = Yii::$app->request->post('compensa');
            if(Yii::$app->request->post('associazione') != null) $model->cashback = Yii::$app->request->post('associazione');
            if(Yii::$app->request->post('formazione') != null) $model->cashback = Yii::$app->request->post('formazione');
            if ($model->save()) {                        
                return Json::encode(["success" => true, 'message' => 'Dati aggiornati']);
            }
        }
        
        // Mostra il form di modifica
        return $this->render('_opzioni_carriera', [
            'parent' => $model,
        ]);
    }
```

anyone can help me? i hope i explained my problem in a good form, but my english is not the best, i know. Anyway thanks in aadvance to everyone who want to try to help me, if you need anything other you can easily ask.

I tried every everything, also a logger but nothing worked

Like someone suggest these are the rules of the model AnagraficaOpzioni, but like i said prevously model->validate() works, for this reason i think the problem is not over there

```
    public function rules()
    {
        
        return [
            [['id_anagrafica'], 'required'],
            [['id_anagrafica'], 'integer'],
            [['cashback', 'compensa', 'associazione', 'formazione'], 'required', 'on'=>['update']],
            [['cashback', 'compensa', 'associazione', 'formazione'], 'integer'],
            
            [['id_anagrafica', 'cashback', 'compensa', 'associazione', 'formazione',], 'safe', 'on'=>['search']],
            
        ];
    }
```

Comment: Please post your rules() from the model.

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, looks like you are loading all your data in single attribute. i.e. **$model->cashback**;

You can try with

```
$model->cashback = Yii::$app->request->post('cashback');
$model->compensa = Yii::$app->request->post('compensa');
$model->associazione = Yii::$app->request->post('associazione');
$model->formazione = Yii::$app->request->post('formazione');
```